# AWS Glue - How to import extra.py files in a subfolder/directory?

Tags: python, aws-glue

My directory structure for the Glue extra.py/library files looks like this:

```
├── script1.py
├── folder1
│   └── script2.py
```

I can import script1.py like normal:

```
from script1 import foo
```

But when I try for script2.py:

```
from folder1.script2 import foo
```

it doesn't work and it will trigger an exception saying `Module folder1 not found`.

Any help on this?

Comment: I read in the documentation that `Only individual files are supported, not a directory path`, on your example, are there limitations on your approach if you consider all your files within a folder and then considering it as a `.whl` file?

Comment: Yeah, I've read that too in the documentation and was wondering is that some sort of workaround in managing a large library of files.

I never tried with a `.whl` but I would like to avoid that as it adds additional steps to setup a Glue job. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a "__init__.py" file in the folder1.

This is useful for understanding about "__init__.py".

[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)